# How to get angle from longitude and latitude using Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

OpenLayers is completely free, Open Source JavaScript which makes it easy to put a dynamic map in any web page.
I am using Openlayers in my project. Here is the problem which I am facing in it:

Using OpenLayers I am able to get Longitude and Latitude but I want the angle from the Openlayers.

So is there any API available in OpenLayer which converts the lat and long to angle. I did try to find API in the openlayers "Util" section but was not able to get it.

ofcourse there are many math functions which can do that but I am curious to get it through Openlayers only.

Comment: If Lat and Lot mentioned above are the x and y coordinates on the map. Then angle (@) between them is tan @ = y/x;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `feature.geometry` or write util function for  angle calculation, for example:

```
OpenLayers.Util.angle = function (x, y) {
    return Math.tan(y/x);
}
```